# trying to assign a variable to JS object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very new to JS world. what I have done is,created a form, in which i am pulling form field values into variables and assigning them to an object(obj), again i am assigning the 'obj' object to 'param' object, console.log(param) gives me undefined. Any help will be appreciated

[I have put my code here](http://jsbin.com/joximumi/1/edit)

```
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" id="user-profile-form" method="post" action=""   enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off" novalidate="novalidate"><div><div class="bd-section bd-section-user-profile">
     <fieldset data-user-email="" class="fs-email-name">
     <h3>Name and Email</h3>
     <div id="edit-field-first-name" class="field-type-text field-name-field-first-name field-widget-text-textfield form-wrapper">
     <div id="field-first-name-add-more-wrapper">
     <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-field-first-name-und-0-value">
     <label for="edit-field-first-name-und-0-value">First Name <span title="This field is     required." class="form-required">*</span></label>
     <input type="textbox" maxlength="14" size="60" value="" name="field_first_name" id="edit-field-first-name-und-0-value" class="text-full form-text required">
      <div class="faux-label" style="display: none;">First Name</div>
      </div>
      </div></div>       
       <div id="edit-field-last-name" class="field-type-text field-name-field-last-name field-widget-text-textfield form-wrapper">
      <div id="field-last-name-add-more-wrapper"><div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-field-last-name-und-0-value">
       <label for="edit-field-last-name-und-0-value">Last Name <span title="This field is required." class="form-required">*</span></label>
       <input type="text" maxlength="14" size="60" value="" name="field_last_name[und][0][value]" id="edit-field-last-name-und-0-value" class="text-full form-text required">
      <div class="faux-label" style="display: none;">Last Name</div>
      </div>
     </div></div>       
    <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-mail">
       <label for="edit-mail">E-mail address <span title="This field is required." class="form-required">*</span></label>
       <input type="text" class="form-text required email" maxlength="254" size="60" value="" name="mail" id="edit-mail">
       <div class="faux-label" style="display: none;">email@email.com</div>
    </div>
   </fieldset>
</div>

    <div id="edit-actions--2" class="form-actions form-wrapper">
      <input type="submit" class="form-submit" value="Save Changes" name="op" id="edit-submit-ca">
     <input type="submit" class="form-submit" value="Delete your account" name="op" id="edit-cancel"><a href="/" class="edit-cancel-changes">Cancel</a></div></div>
   </form>        </div><!-- .col-left -->


    </div>
   <script>

     function user_pref_data(){
      var FirstName;
      var LastName;
      var email;
      var param={};
      var obj = {};


$("#edit-field-first-name-und-0-value").focusout(function(){
   FirstName = this.value;
   console.log(FirstName)
});
$("#edit-field-last-name-und-0-value").focusout(function(){
   LastName = this.value;
 });
 $("#edit-mail").focusout(function(){
  email = this.value;
});
  obj.frstnam = FirstName;
  obj.lstnam = LastName;
  obj.eml = email;
  param.param = obj;
  console.log(param);
}
 $("input#edit-submit-ca").on('click', function(event){
//alert("hi")

 user_pref_data();
 return false;

});

});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Questions need to provide enough detail and description of the problem to allow us to help you to solve it. In this case - can you please post the *relevant* code here in this question and highlight the part where your problem is occuring.

Comment: Hi, I have added the link as well.

Comment: @scrowler is right. You can read more about how you shouldn't just link to other pages in [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/why/we/shouldn't/link/so/much)

Comment: ok I will keep in mind.. I will try to add more details about the problem, I am facing in my next question onwards.. BTW I have included the code as well. Thank you very much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [**DEMO JS BIN code**](http://jsbin.com/xasucuba/1/edit)

```
var obj = {};
function user_pref_data(){
   var param={};

   var FirstName;
   var LastName;
   var email;

   param.param = obj;
   console.log(param);
}
$("input#edit-submit-ca").on('click', function(event){
  //alert("hi")

  user_pref_data();
  return false;

});
$("#edit-field-first-name-und-0-value").focusout(function(){
       FirstName = this.value;
      obj.frstnam = FirstName;
       console.log(FirstName);
});
$("#edit-field-last-name-und-0-value").focusout(function(){
      LastName = this.value;
      obj.lstnam = LastName;
});
$("#edit-mail").focusout(function(){
      email = this.value;
      obj.eml = email;
});
```

Made some changes in your code. Add this.
The focusout event functions cannot be defined in another function for them to occur.

As your function `user_pref_data()` was getting called only on submit action, those focusout events never occured.

Answer (score 0):

You have access the value on `focusout` event and even you have bind that event handler on submitting page that is bad practice. normally all event handler has to be bind at the beginning. check the solution below.

```
function user_pref_data(){
  var param={};
  var obj = {};
  var FirstName;
  var LastName;
  var email;

  FirstName = $("#edit-field-first-name-und-0-value").val();
  LastName = $("#edit-field-last-name-und-0-value").val();
  email = $("#edit-mail").val();

   obj.frstnam = FirstName;
   obj.lstnam = LastName;
   obj.eml = email;
   param.param = obj;
   console.log(param);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to get the values of form field on `focusout`?

Try this :

```
var FirstName;
  var LastName;
  var email;  
$("#edit-field-first-name-und-0-value").focusout(function(){
       FirstName = this.value;
       console.log(FirstName);
    });
  $("#edit-field-last-name-und-0-value").focusout(function(){
      LastName = this.value;
    });
  $("#edit-mail").focusout(function(){
      email = this.value;
    });

function user_pref_data(){
  var param={};
  var obj = {};  

   obj.frstnam = FirstName;
   obj.lstnam = LastName;
   obj.eml = email;
   param.param = obj;
   console.log(param);
}
$("input#edit-submit-ca").on('click', function(event){
  //alert("hi")

  user_pref_data();
  return false;

});
```

[Working Example - Check your console](http://jsfiddle.net/QVpcU/)

Jquery [`.focusout()`](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/) event is sent to an element when it, or any element inside of it, loses focus.

Because, In your code you bind the .focusout() event when the function `user_pref_data()` is executing and that time the foucs-out event not fired.

Answer (score 0):

Very strange, but I fixed it changing `$("#id")` to `document.getElementById()`.
change this line:

```
$("#edit-field-first-name-und-0-value").focusout(function(){
      FirstName = this.value;
    });
```

to this:

```
FirstName = document.getElementById("edit-field-first-name-und-0-value").value;
```

<strike>maybe you forgot to include jQuery libraries?</strike>
Oh, I see you do included them.

Answer (score 0):

Rashim Javiya's example is perfect but just to add to that and why your code wasn't working is because javascript is based on an event loop. the function user_pref_data() was called on the submit event that called focus out events that had already passed (personally i wouldnt fetch input data on focus out events--refer to Rashims code above but below is an example of your same //with few modifcations // code working because I initilize your function without attaching it to an event.

```
(function user_data_function() {
var param;
var obj = {};
var FirstName;
var LastName;
var email;

$("#edit-field-first-name-und-0-value").focusout(function(){
   FirstName = this.value;
   console.log(FirstName);
});
$("#edit-field-last-name-und-0-value").focusout(function(){
  LastName = this.value;
});
$("#edit-mail").focusout(function(){
  email = this.value;
});


$("input#edit-submit-ca").on('click', function(event){
//alert("hi")

obj.frstnam = FirstName;
obj.lstnam = LastName;
obj.eml = email;
param = $.param( obj );
console.log(param);
event.preventDefault(); // works same as 'return false' in your code but this is best practice

});
})(); // initilize and call function at same time
```

again not the way i would write this code, but for demonstation purposes i hope this clears up how the event loop works with javascript